# Pass a null terminated string to bash function

Tags: bash

My **exported** function :

```
myfunc(){
# Some operation with null terminated string
# If I use $1, is it guaranteed that it is a null terminated string?
}
```

For the sake of this example, consider

```
find . -type -f -print0 | while read -rd '' line
do
myfunc "$line"
done
```

Comment: If you use `"$1"`, then I think so.

Comment: Bash strings are always NUL-terminated, which means that they cannot contain NUL characters. Perhaps that wasn't what you meant, though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're using `print0` then make sure you use empty `IFS=` in addition to `-d ''` in `read` to make null as delimiter:

```
while IFS= read -r -d '' line; do
   myfunc "$line"
done < <(find . -type f -print0)
```

As shown you can also avoid a pipeline and use process substitution.

Comment: Thanks .. Why `IFS=` in addition to `d ''`?

Comment: @mona_sax, because unless `IFS` is cleared, trailing whitespace can be pruned by `read`.

Comment: @anubhava, ...though with only one argument passed to `read` and no `-a`, there isn't really *splitting* going on...